# Bounty expired, 4 upvotes and no points received

Tags: support, bounties

I answered a bounty question. My answer has 4 up-votes and the rest have 0 votes. The bounty expired earlier today. I don't see the points from the bounty anywhere. What's going on?

Comment: Got a link to the bounty question in question?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643636/using-client-certificate-not-in-certificate-store/

Comment: If you want another free bounty, link your accounts (see the "accounts" tab on your profile). Free rep.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Was your answer posted *before* or *after* the bounty was added? It must be after (I think edits count, but don't quote me).

Also, there is sometimes a delay of a few hours in awarding the bounty.

In some ***very rare*** cases the bounty has been redacted by mods - usually to migrate the question between sites.

See [the blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/reputation-bounty-for-unanswered-questions/) (re what happens if [the OP] doesn't accept an answer):

> Any answer that was a) provided after the bounty period started and b) has 2 or more upvotes is automatically accepted after 7 days.

---

Edit; now you've posted the question number, I can see that you posted after the bounty...

> `Bounty creation of 300 rep on question id = 1643636 Nov 3 at 15:02`
>
> answered Nov 6 at 17:46 Gonzalo

So I expect it is just the delay. Give it an hour or so...

Comment: It was posted after the bounty was added. If it's just a delay, I'll mark this answer as accepted when I see the points showing up. Thanks.

Comment: Looks like the bounty just showed up. Problem solved.

Comment: Nice. The bounty points are there now. Thanks!

Comment: I'm thinking that edit's to an answer posted before the bounty was set don't count as I never got the bounty that was offered on this:  http://serverfault.com/questions/55532/hardening-wordpress-on-iis6