# Is it possible to accept an answer on a bounty question after the bounty expires?

Tags: discussion, bounties, accepted-answer

It's well documented that bounty questions whose bounty period expires without an accepted answer have some delay in auto-accepting an answer ([here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13186/is-there-a-delay-after-bounty-expires-before-the-top-voted-answer-is-automaticall) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29246/bounty-expired-4-upvotes-and-no-points-received)).  Is it possible for the OP to accept an answer on an expired bounty question after the bounty period expires and before the auto-accept job runs?  If so, can the user accept any answer or only the one that would have been selected by the auto-accept feature?

Comment: Whee! I love race conditions!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why an answer can't be accepted after an unresolved bounty?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1413/why-an-answer-cant-be-accepted-after-an-unresolved-bounty)

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure I've had full rep (i.e. not the half-rep for auto-selection) from a bounty question **after** it formally expired, with a comment from the OP at the same time, so yes, in theory this is (or at some point: was) possible.