# Why can't I accept an answer to my question?

Tags: support, specific-question, bounties, accepted-answer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unable to accept answer for a question with a bounty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32358/unable-to-accept-answer-for-a-question-with-a-bounty)

I have [a question on Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/6583/why-does-my-iphones-audio-when-played-over-bluetooth-stop-when-the-display-turns/) that I would like to accept an answer for, but there's no checkmark to click next to any of the answers.

Why can't I accept an answer?

Comment: Did you add a bounty to it in the past?

Answer (score 3):

If you ever had a bounty set on it, and said bounty expired, you permanently lose the ability to select an answer afterward:

- [Why an answer can’t be accepted after an unresolved bounty?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1413/why-an-answer-cant-be-accepted-after-an-unresolved-bounty)
- [Is it possible to accept an answer on a bounty question after the bounty expires?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31873/is-it-possible-to-accept-an-answer-on-a-bounty-question-after-the-bounty-expires)
- [Unable to accept answer for a question with a bounty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32358/unable-to-accept-answer-for-a-question-with-a-bounty)

And probably several other examples ...

Comment: This would be why we need to add the bounty stuff to the edit history... I know there's a Feature request on it somewhere, but I'm guessing it could use a bump.

Comment: Hmm... I don't recall setting a bounty on it, but I might have.

Comment: @jasonh, according to your reputation history, you set a bounty on it around July 18th. (If you ever forget if you've added a bounty, just look for a dip in your reputation graph)

Comment: @Brandon: Thanks for the validation. That does make this officially a duplicate of 32358, so I'm gonna vote to close now. (I held off until there was validation that this is the bounty issue.)

Answer (score -1):

> no checkmarks to click next to each answer

The checkmarks are images so something could be keeping them from loading. You could check if you have images disabled or maybe some ad blocking software giving a false positive.