# Auto bounty award bug?

Tags: bug, bounties

From the Stack Overflow FAQ:

> If the bounty was started by the question owner, and the question owner accepts an answer during the bounty period, and the bounty expires without an explicit award – we assume the bounty owner liked the answer **they accepted** and award it the full bounty amount at the time of bounty expiration.

Why isn't my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6718707/843985) awarded the bounty (it has been accepted during the bounty period)?

=== UPDATE ===

Meanwhile, a different answer is (half) arwarded.

Should a during the bounty time updated, most (new) votes received and accepted answer don't have more priority than a not accepted new answer with fewer votes?

I'm very surprised, and think that the bounty starter thinks similarly now. I'm just a little disappointed, because I think many other users also don't understand these priorities of auto awarding.

Comment: Certainly looks like a bug - the bounty was not awarded to _anyone_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [bounty privilege info page](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/set-bounties):

> If you do not award the bounty within 24 hours of the bounty period ending, half the bounty value will be automatically be awarded to the top voted answer **posted after the bounty start**, provided it has a score of at least 2. If no new answer matches this requirement, no reputation will be awarded at all, and the reputation used on the bounty will be lost forever

See the bold part - your answer was posted before the bounty started, thus not eligible to get the automatic bounty award.

However, after further reading both sources looks like it's a bug indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Bounty will be awarded,for accepted answer after completion of grace period. It may take max 4-5 hours after grace period also. Or if you are lucky you will get it in less span after grace period. Because it's not manually awarded bounty it's system auto awarded bounty.

Yes you will surely get full bounty after completion of grace period provided OP doesn't award it to anybody.

Grace period is kept for giving time(24 hours) to award bounty. If OP doesn't award bounty in grace period to anybody then whole bounty(100%) will be given to accepted answer.
It is kept like this because OP might want to award to different person in grace period though OP had accepted answer. You will have to wait 24 hours. Be calm bounty is yours provided OP doesn't award it to anybody.

Comment: Grace period is over on that bounty...

Comment: It may take 4-5 hours. But you will definitely get bounty.  [I am suffered from this a lot times.Experienced guy...-:(](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1045444/somnath-muluk?tab=bounties).

Comment: Possible source :P http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/29247/172936

Comment: @Lix: Firstly I havn't checked Grace period is over. But those things(OP's query) are also happened with me. Source given by you I have seen now which is very different. I have seen very 1st time.

Comment: The entire answer is not really related - I was only referring to Marc's comment about the delay...